# Appropriate Sample Size Formula

Tags: sample-size, random-variable

I have a uniform distribution set which contains different similarity scores. This similarity scores is linked with documents in which I am planning to examine. However, this set is big, and it is difficult to check it completely. So, I would like to randomly choose from it. And to determine how many time should I choose from the set, I am planning to calculate sample size to get minimum sample size.

I am not sure which formula is best in this case. I came across this formula which I found understandable and clear for me:

$$ n = \frac{Z^2 pq}{e^2} $$

where n = required sample size.

Z = the normal curve constant that represents the level of confidence.

E = the desired level of precision estimated.

p = the estimated proportion of attribute that is present in a population and q is the 1-p.

Is it appropriate to use this one? If so, I would like to know what is the appropriate value of p?

Comment: More information needed about what you are trying to do. What is 'uniform distribution set' and why are you randomly choosing from it? Are you trying to estimate some quantity?

Comment: Edited the question